# Generic field of an object returned from a function (hook)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm working on React hook, which returns props for inputs (label, value, onChange handlers), based on a schema. The schema for a specific field has a "variant" field with value "string" or "number". I want to achieve that a type of specific output field is "generically" typed based on the schema. For example, if property "variant" in the schema is "string", then  "onStringChange" is presented in props. If "variant" is "number", then "onNumberChange". Is there any way how to achieve this?

For clarity, the following is an example of use

```
const Form = () => {

  const fieldsProps = createFieldsPropsHook({   // <--- this is an example of using the function with "schema"
    firstname: {
        label: "Your firstname",
        variant: 'string'  // <--- variant 'string' so I want "onStringChange" handler
    },
    age: {
        label: "Your age",
        variant: 'number'    // <--- variant "number" so I want "onNumberChange"
    }
  })

  return (<div>
    <Input 
    value={ fieldsProps.firstname.value }
    label = { fieldsProps.firstname.label }
    onChange = {fieldsProps.firstname.onStringChange} // <--- string handler
    />

    <Input 
    value={ fieldsProps.age.value }
    label={ fieldsProps.age.label }
    onChange={fieldsProps.age.onNumberChange}   // <--- number handler
    />
  </div>)
}
```

For the example above I want to output like this

```
fieldsProps: {
    firstname: {
        onStringChange: (v: any) => void
        // label, etc...
    },
    age: {
        onNumberChange: (v: any) => void
        // label, etc...
    }
}
```

This is my attempt

```
type Schema = Record<string, { variant: 'string', label: string } | { variant: 'number', label: string }>

type StringFieldProps = { onStringChange: (value: string) => void, label: string, value: string }
type NumberFieldProps = { onNumberChange: (value: number) => void, label: string, value: number }

function createFieldsPropsHook<T extends Schema>(schema: T) {

    // ... some implementation ...

    return output as Record<keyof T, StringFieldProps | NumberFieldProps>
}
```

but I only achieved that all the fields are the same and without handlers

[image]
[image]

So, how to change the type of individual output field based on the schema? Is it even possible
in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map over each key (with a mapped type like `{ [K in keyof T]: SomeType }`) in order to process each key's variant.

Then you need a way to lookup the field props return type based on that value. For that let's create an intermediate type that matches variants to their output types:

```
type VariantLookup = {
    string: StringFieldProps
    number: NumberFieldProps
}
```

This should make it very easy to add more variants (`"date"`, `"checkbox"`, etc.)

Now we can type the return value like so:

```
function createFieldsPropsHook<T extends Schema>(schema: T): {
    [K in keyof T]:
        VariantLookup[T[K]["variant"]]
} {
    // TODO: Implement...
    return {} as any
}
```

`T[K]["variant"]` gets the `"string"` or `"number"` from the schema, and the `VariantLookup[...]` returns the field props type from the lookup helper type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=31&ssc=44&pln=31&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQEoTgewCcATAHgGdhCBLAOwHMAaKAbygDdUbVbgAuKAHJKNBoOYAbVACMIEgSLr0oAXygAfVhy7Ue-IbQCuyWYXFQps+VEUNVAPgBQj0JFhUlAMWpziABUJ8MHJMLXxaGA8GAGEEHnoIAQAKTglDRJso+gBKTHsOfGpiSRk5BSzmVPTy0WUVF3BoADljU29fAKCQrDZwlpMIQlj4jJTUNIyjAcJcjHz2QuKLUutbJm0JgSnTVWc6YEGAM1Q4aAA1HT0AGXx8AGtDMFZHKFfM2oFI2vaJf0Dgl5vbaDAT9No+X6dAH1RyHQy0ODAajhKBwQgQVAHH7EchQ8gACVud1IABUoBAAB4HWg42CIFCoexJcj0tACEnZAQsQGvADaAGkoHQoHcICB8IcoCSALoCC7cXg3e6PXkkgXS3kAIk4CuAmul0scam5bygAHozVKAPIAEStAgAksgwBIUBBeAA6L08qDo4CGQi0VhqVAhHggI3OAi0ShQQ4QnF40JojFYhO4-4EolJNivC1QUgAWmLUGACGoIQrUB45IpqGdrqgEqghnISlLSDj8MRyKDAHdqGWoJqWUg0JqffHCJRaPWMibTW9LGVhwBNfABuPUafAWfICCaxg+0063S8ATCLKCPOWosl096IRra-kfBQB1QPuPzXhL5KYYMAeUBxDSrqED6KhHqaqAJFyx5LisAiauum4wQeUGLq8D7ngYrSDNebz5nehbaLqw7AoQmo2G+H5frww59HhQwgQkE6mvUKjZM4sLpniHpTjOc4er+WQAQkSSCMQgxgIIuT5gA4rcxAAIQ8b4GZdB6aHCbQYKDGJEBJAAbAArHJlqKfgKlAA)

---

> *Is it possible to make a "variant" optional? For example, if "variant" is undefined, then use StringFieldProps*

Sure is!

First change your schema type to this:

```
type Schema = Record<string, { variant?: 'string' | 'number', label: string }>
```

This says the variant is string, number, or missing entirely. This allows us to check for the 'variant' property without a type error.

Now we can use a conditional type to check to see if the `variant` exists as a key in the lookup type. If it does, then use that variants return type, else return the default of `StringFieldProps`

```
function createFieldsPropsHook<T extends Schema>(schema: T): {
    [K in keyof T]:
        T[K]["variant"] extends keyof Schema
            ? VariantLookup[T[K]["variant"]]
            : StringFieldProps
} {
    // TODO: Implement...
    return {} as any
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make a "variant" optional? For example, if "variant" is undefined, then use StringFieldProps?